# Did we get near Pluto with our current technology?

Tags: universe, data

I was sent from Skeptic to here.

We all know that NASA has successfully carried out the mission for getting near Pluto.
More [here](http://fortune.com/2015/07/15/nasa-pluto-data-earth/).

It is very difficult for me to accept that we already have the technology necessary to transmit data in such a distances. They transmit data over a billion miles and still we haven't been able to cover the most of the Earth with the internet? 4.4 billion people still don't have an access to the internet.

The cellphone coverage is limited and you don't get the reception for your phone all the time. There is many other areas where the transmitters have their limits here on Earth. So what is the catch?

Is NASA really able to transmit data over the billion miles (unimaginable distance) but still struggle to provide internet/phone coverage on Earth?

Comment: Voyagers [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1) & [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2) have gone further than [New Horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about technology & global disparity thereof and not physics.

Comment: @Grasper Just think about the difference in transmission geometry (due to the spherical shape of the earth and the emptiness of space) and antenna size: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Network – not exactly what you have in your pocket (or on rooftops).

Comment: Also we have satellite telephones, that work pretty much everywhere on earth. So it is a question of cost per band-width, not of general possibility. The New Horizons downstream is less than the good old 56k modem ...

Comment: @SebastianRiese, sounds good. I read about the X band and that explains it. Thanks

Comment: Also, how can we possibly be asked to believe that the Empire State Building is 102 stories high, when all over the earth there are buildings that are not even 2 stories high?

Comment: "X band" doesn't explain anything:  You are talking about two totally different problems.  On the one hand, connecting a single spacecraft to a single Earth station with a lot of empty space between them; Vs. connecting billions of computers to billions of other computers in a way that lets everyone connect to whoever they want, whenever they want, in a matter of milliseconds, without mixing up the signals.  You are talking about _providing computers_ and _providing electricity_ to the billions of people who don't have them,... I could go on..., probably for days...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "catches" as you call them are at least threefold:

1. Cellphones require transmission and receiving hardware that fit in your hand / desktop computer *and* be almost omnidirectional, *i.e.* able to receive transmissions from any direction. In contrast, deep space probes are tracked with extremely directional, huge antennas of hundreds of meters diameter scale; often these are grouped into phased arrays yielding effective antenna sizes of the scale of continents. Even the transmission hardware on the spacecraft itself far exceeds the power and antenna size (therefore gain) of any cellphone.
2. Cellphones and internet require large datarates. However, if datarate is no object, you can transmit over arbitrary distances simply by slowing the transmission down and using error correcting coding. This is indeed so for New Horizons: the transmission rate is *two kilobits per second* - a 1980s telephone modem speed (remember Kermit?). The reason this works is the famous Shannon noisy channel coding theorem: that each signal to noise ratio defines a quantity called the *channel capacity* in bits per second and, as long as the information transmission rate does not exceed this capacity, there exists an error correcting code that will reduce the error probability to as near as you like to nought if you're willing to use long enough data frames to implement the code. The capacity decreases with along with the signal to noise ratio, but it is always positive (but small for low signal to noise ratios). This is why we can still receive transmissions from Voyager 1 and 2. Voyager 1 currently transmits at 160 bits per second: a 1960s teletype printer rate!
3. We have a clear line of sight to New Horizons. Not so if your transmission tower is behind a hill and you're on the lee side.

As user DJohnM notes:

> Another example: the GPS Navigation Message is transmitted at around 60 bits per second!

Comment: Another example:  the GPS Navigation Message is transmitted at around 60 bits per second!